# Widget sensitive/gray look change with window focus causes too much delay

Tags: gtk3, gnome-shell

I like to adjust or disable a feature of gtk3 (or gnome-shell?) because it causes a delay or at least need to remove the delay when bringing a window in/out of focus. My multi window application suffers from this delay:

I see is that all widgets like buttons, entries, etc. are set to in-sensitive/gray look at time the window they are contained is loosing focus and they return to normal when the window focus returns. I tried to turn off animations, but that does not disable this behavior.

My old program version based on gtk2 based does not have this feature (same gnome shell). So I conclude gtk3 is some how managing this.

I so far was not able to find out how to disable this.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the default (Adwaita) desktop theme, and as such you can't disable it for one application. Each window's widgets get the `:backdrop` CSS pseudo-class when it is not the active window, and the Adwaita theme styles them that way.

Your best bet is to pick another desktop theme.

Comment: Thanks for the good hint. I was not really successful finding a good working non default than the Adwaita scheme for my system (Debian testing). So I tried to customize a copy of Adwaita and yes found a lot of  entry:backdrop { ...;    transition: 200ms ease-out; }  statements. I reduced the transition to 20ms, may be I should disable it? There are many entries for all kind of gtk3 elements... Is there any consistent way or editor or generator to do this better than editing manually? Thanks.

Comment: With 20ms it works faster but looks a little flickery -- my application has a few more entries (>100) and a like -- even I do have a pretty decent i7 12 core system with Nvidia Quadro K2200 graphics, but running two 4K screens.

Comment: And yes I do have a more high power Nividia GLX970 at home -- I have a feeling it behaves a little nicer / smoother there...

Comment: The Adwaita theme is written in SCSS, so you might try to compile a copy of GTK yourself and edit the SCSS source.